# Is there a quick way to search for a given researcher's past collaborators/co-authors?

Tags: collaboration, authorship

Is there a website or software for one to search for all the past co-authors/collaborators of a given researcher?

I can of course go through the researcher's publication and get the names one by one, but just wonder if there is a shortcut way of doing this.

Comment: Most bibliographic systems include this, for example, Google Scholar has a co-authors network, as well as Microsoft Academic Search.

Answer (score 7):

For researchers in computer science, another approach is to use DBLP, which is free. For example, [this is the coauthor list for me](http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/pers/hd/v/Venkatasubramanian%3aSuresh.html#coauthors) on my DBLP page. It is reached by going to the researcher page at DBLP, and then clicking the little 'people' icon on the right hand side.

Comment: Not working for me

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do this with many scientific indexing service.  Personally, I like [Scopus](http://www.scopus.com).  It is subscription-based, though.

First, find the [author page](http://www.scopus.com/authid/detail.url?origin=resultslist&authorId=31267510200&zone=).  I find this easiest by searching for the title of any publications by the said author, because most names are far from unique.

[image: Screenshot for my author page]

Here, you can click on co-authors.  This will give you a list.  For example, I currently have [31 co-authors](http://www.scopus.com/search/submit/coAuthorSearch.url?authorId=31267510200&origin=AuthorProfile&sot=al&sdt=coaut&st1=Holl&st2=Gerrit), here sorted by number of publications:

[image]

Note that this doesn't state how many documents in particular I have in common with this co-author.  To get that, click instead on [Documents](http://www.scopus.com/search/submit/author.url?author=Holl%2c+Gerrit&origin=AuthorProfile&authorId=31267510200), then, under *Author Name*, on *More*:

[image]

You can get similar information through the Author Evaluator → co-authors.

Needless to say, 100% of my publications have myself as an author ;)

Comment: Web of Science has the same feature

Comment: Both Scopus and Web of Science are commercial systems. By default, you assume that the OP has an appropriate academic access to these, but this may not be so. Sometimes, coverage between the systems may differ. Scopus, an Elsevier product, would be adamant in promoting Elsevier titles, but not so much Wiley or Springer titles that it may be parsing for co-authors with a lesser accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Google scholar tries to do this, but it looks as though the author needs to have a profile, and so do the co-authors, and either both authors need to have added the publication to their record, or one author needs to have added the others (in addition to them being named on the paper's author list).

ResearcherID can apparently do the same, again, if the author has a profile, but the search doesn't appear to work (I can't even find myself without the ResearcherID), and it can only cross-populate the author list from papers which the author has added using web of science.

So if your target person has a google scholar profile that they maintain nicely, and that's common in the field, you might do quite well.

Otherwise, can you automate scraping their publications page?

Comment: The scholar package in R can get a list of co-authors; I gave an example in my answer to a related question https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/163709/258

Comment: Where does scholar allow that?

Comment: @borgr scholar.google.com, go to the author's profile, Co-authors are listed on the right, click "view all".  But as I said in the answer, it only works for those with the common articles in their profiles, so not many of mine show up

Answer (score 0):

It is widely assumed that [Web of Science](http://thomsonreuters.com/web-of-science/) is the most comprehensive citation index. It is also true that it is not the most intuitive web interface available, but it is very powerful.

As an example, you can create criteria such as counting the number of citations for an author excluding past co-authors. This one is great to measure impact outside one's own circle of acquaintances.

*I would have included a link to the search page, but unfortunately I don't have institutional subscription for that service anymore.*