# How to retrieve total number of co-authors a researcher has published with?

Tags: authorship, tools

I understand that Google Scholar offers this service, but it has limitations and does not offer the correct number of co-authors. Are there any other websites or tools to retrieve the total count of co-authors?

Comment: Pen and paper? Or do you need and automated process for many authors?

Comment: In what field ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a quick way to search for a given researcher's past collaborators/co-authors?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12461/is-there-a-quick-way-to-search-for-a-given-researchers-past-collaborators-co-au)

Comment: the question could use clarification. Different databases have different levels of coverage so the answer to "correct number of co-authors" could be difficult to answer for some authors with many citations.

Answer (score 2):

A very similar question was previously discussed [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/12461/is-there-a-quick-way-to-search-for-a-given-researchers-past-collaborators-co-au). I suggest you use the bibliographic database *Scopus* by Elsevier, which is an established reference (at least where I live). To update the answer by user "gerrit" (Scopus has changed a bit in the last 8 years), [search](https://www.scopus.com/search/form.uri?zone=TopNavBar&origin=AuthorProfile&display=basic#author) for the name of the author of interest and click on "Co-Authors": [image: Screenshot of Scopus page for an author]

This will give you the complete list:[image: List of co-authors]

Note: Scopus is a paid service by Elsevier, so the free version you can access without registering is quite limited. Ask the support at your university library to check whether you have access to the paid version.

Comment: To add to this answer, Web of Science is another database that is often used and you may have access to through your institution.

Comment: @realkevlar good point. For this, go to https://www.webofscience.com/wos/author/search, search by name and surname, then you find the list of co-authors at the bottom of the right-side column